# Git merge conflicts during PRs

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I did a bit unusual setup where repositories were first set up, instead of populating the `master` branch with project files, a `transfer` branch was created and populated. Then, files were pull into `development` via PR and then again into `master` via another PR.

And, going forward, topic branches are created off `development` branch. Once done, PR was created for `topic` --> `development` and another PR for `development` --> `master`. But, I keep getting merge conflict for second PR `development` --> `master` such as **Added in Both**, **Edited in Both** etc on Azure DevOps.

Right now, only squash merge is used to complete PR into both `development` and `master`.

What I want to know is whether those merge conflicts I am seeing happen due to the original setup of the repository or squash merge. The `diff` of PR for `development` and `master` also contains a lot of changes I do not expect, too.

I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflicts happen because you are using "squash" merge and continuously reintegrate one branch. With "squash" you are not doing a real merge (in other words: the history is not connected). Instead you are creating a single new commit on `master` branch.

Later, when you try to merge `development` to `master`, all previous changes from development would be merged again (but they already exist in `master`). That's why you see conflicts.

I see 2 options:

- Don't use "squash" at all for re-integration branches and use regular merges
- Re-create the `development` from `master` after every single merge

Comment: “With "squash" you are not doing a real merge” I wish people would just get this fact clear. It’s a terrible name. A squash merge is not any kind of a merge! It’s a terrible idea, and this use case is one clear reason why.

Comment: Thanks. By regular merge, are you referring to **basic merge (no fast-forward)**, I suppose? Four available merge types of Azure DevOps here: https://prnt.sc/vres0r

Comment: @KZee yes exactly, I'm talking about a "non-forward merge" which will create a new merge commit with 2 parents. Those merge commits are required if you plan to merge a branch multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Just to build on knittl's existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65041823/341994), here's a scenario you can enact in the comfort of your own home to demonstrate how easily a so-called "squash merge" can result in a conflict.

We start by making file on `master` and committing it:

```
$ git init
$ echo "a" >> a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m'start'
```

Now we create `develop` and modify that file:

```
$ git branch develop
$ git checkout develop
$ echo "b" > a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m'changed a to b'
```

We return to `master` and do a "squash merge", and it appears to work fine:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash develop
$ git commit -m'a squash commit from develop'
```

So far so good. Now we make a terrible mistake: we do it *again*. We switch to `develop` and modify that file some more:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ echo "c" > a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m'changed b to c'
```

And we return to `master` and do a "squash merge" *again*:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash develop
```

Aaaaaand we get a conflict. Game over.

---

What happened? Well, the problem is that a "squash merge" is *not a merge*. It's a sort of self-inflicted patch. It constructs a configuration of the index (staging area), and you commit it. In my enactment above, we committed it as a separate step; with GitHub, it is committed for you. But the point is that that commit, although it contains the *changes* that would accrue from a real merge, is *not* a merge commit: it is just a normal commit, as if you had done those changes yourself, working directly on `master`.

Well, what does it mean to make the changes that would accrue from a real merge? To answer that, you have to know how a merge works:

1. A merge starts by calculating the common point from which the merging branches diverged: the *merge base*.
2. It then calculates two diffs: From the merge base to the end of the first branch, and from the merge base to the end of the second branch.
3. Finally, it enacts *both diffs* on the merge base.

Okay, so try that yourself, using a thought experiment.

For the first "squash merge" in my scenario above, the merge base is "start", where *a.txt* is "a". So:

- On `master`, it is still "a", so there is no diff to enact.
- On `develop`, it is "b", so the diff is *change-"a"-to-"b"*.

So, to form the "squash merge" commit, we just change "a" to "b".

Very well, let's proceed to the second "squash merge" in my scenario. Here's the thing: *the merge base is still "start"*, where *a.txt* is *still* "a". So:

- On `master`, the diff is *change-"a"-to-"b"*.

  (Note that `master` doesn't "know" that this happened because of any kind of merge; it thinks that this change was performed independently by someone working directly on `master`.)
- On `develop`, the diff is *change-"a"-to-"c"*.

But you can't do both; that's a conflict!

So you see, the reason why reusing a branch that was previously squash-merged is troublesome is that *the merge base does not move* (and nothing in the history involves any merging); and so every successive squash merge is a potential conflict with an earlier "squash merge" of the same branch.

Comment: If we do a regular merge, then the "start" for the next merges would be that regular merge commit point, I suppose?

Comment: @KZee Exactly right! And that makes all the difference. Even then, repeatedly merging the same branch into the same other branch _can_ be a bit tricky, but repeatedly squash-merging the same branch into the same other branch is just about _guaranteed_ to be tricky, because the branch history just keeps accumulating.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are great for explaining why this happened. I'd like to simply quantify an easy rule of thumb to determine which Merge Types you can use for which branches. Azure DevOps has the following options when completing a PR:

1. Merge (no fast-forward)
2. Squash Commit
3. Rebase and fast-forward
4. Semi-linear merge

It's OK to use any of those options when completing a PR from `topic` into `development` depending on your preference. But all commits in `development` and `master` are sacred and should not be changed. Note that options 2-4 all potentially rewrite commits on the source branch. For that reason you should:

> Only use the first option of **Merge** when completing a PR when the
> ***source*** branch is  `development` or `master` (and also `release` or `hotfix` in Git Flow).

Azure DevOps allows you to lock down merge types into a branch as the *target*, but unfortunately I don't think you can do it for when the branch is the *source*.

Comment: You are right. We can set branch policies where we can limit merge types (where the branch is the _destination_). That I think is sufficient to prevent me/people from making unwanted commits on _master_ branch.