# Git conflicts not related to files I changed in branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to rebase a branch but it's bringing up conflicts not related to my branch.

So I created branch `app/feature-1` and made my changes
Then I branched off that and did `app/feature-2`. Here I changed 1 file.

I ended up making more changes to `app/feature-1` and landed that to master.

Then I tried to rebase `app/feature-2` but now I'm getting conflicts that are not at all related to the 1 file I changed.

How do I rebase but only deal with conflicts related to my changes? Featute 2 branch should just accept what's in master and look at the 1 file ideally.

Comment: Was `feature-1` merged? If so, how? True merge, or just some sort of "squash" or "rebase" merge?

Comment: just a merge into master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You almost certainly want `git rebase --onto`.  See the last section below (**How to use `git rebase --onto`**) for details.  (I can't make a link to it directly, sorry.)

#### Long

> I'm trying to rebase a branch but it's bringing up conflicts not related to my branch.

That's because branches don't exist.<sup>1</sup>  Don't think in terms of branches.  Think—and work—in terms of *commits*.  Remember what a commit is and does for you, and that `git rebase` works by *copying* some existing set of commits, one at a time as if by `git cherry-pick`,<sup>2</sup> to new-and-improved (well, at least *new:* one can hope for *improved*) commits.  Until you answer [matt's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100496/git-conflicts-not-related-to-files-i-changed-in-branch#comment115093088_65100496), I'll just have to make a few guesses about the commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>OK, that's an overstatement—*something* certainly exists here—but it really *is* why you are seeing conflicts from something you didn't do: you think of your branch as consisting of *your commits*, and that's not the case.  The underlying problem here is the word *branch*.  It doesn't have a single fixed meaning.  As such, when used loosely, it can have whatever meaning you intend at the time, but if you aren't sure what that meaning is, when you use it a second time and it has a different meaning, you can get tripped up by this.  It's as if the word had no meaning at all.

Seriously, look at your own sentence again.  You're trying to rebase *a branch*.  What exactly is that?  It has conflicts not related to *my branch*.  What exactly is that?

<sup>2</sup>Some forms of `git rebase` literally run `git cherry-pick`, and the other forms do the *as if* part (and are gradually becoming less common in Git).

---

#### Git is all about commits

I will revisit this statement soon:

> I ended up making more changes to `app/feature-1` and landed that to master.

There's another problem here, which is this *landed that to master* part.  But let's talk first about commits.

The commit is our key unit of storage in Git.  Because of the way Git is built, we can actually refer to different units of storage, but commits are the interesting ones.  Files are stored *inside* commits, as it were, and branch names like `app/feature-1` can help us—and Git—*find* commits, but it's the commits themselves that matter.  So we need a way to absolutely, positively identify any one individual commit.  We can then point to *that* commit, and talk about it, and see what it is and does.

There is more than one way to talk about a commit, but there's just one way that is absolutely positive like this, and that's to use the commit's *hash ID*.  The hash ID is in fact a unique number, particular to *that one commit*.  No other commit anywhere will ever use the same number.<sup>3</sup>  So the number, expressed in hexadecimal, is—at least when spelled out in its full ugly length—the true name of the commit, as it were.

These numbers, such as [`faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475), are big and ugly and impossible for humans to get right (except via cut-and-paste), so we mostly don't use them.  But they are, in the end, how *Git* finds the commits.  We *can* use them at need, via cut-and-paste, or by taking the first few characters from a commit and typing those in: as long as there isn't some other internal object that starts with the same four or more characters, a prefix of the hash ID is as good as the full thing.

These hash IDs are permanent—well, as permanent as the underlying object in Git's main database—and immutable.  No power on or off Earth can change a hash ID, because despite them being random-*looking*, they're actually completely determined by the internal object's content.  So a commit's content can't be changed—not one bit of it—and hence that commit's hash ID is always *that* ID, in *every* Git repository everywhere.

So that's the absolute sure way to *find* a commit: present its raw number to Git.  Your Git will look into your main repository database and see if it has a commit object whose number is the given hash ID.  If so, that's the right commit.  This is also how Gits *exchange* commits—and other Git internal objects—with each other: they just present the ID.  If both Gits have the ID, it's the same object and they both have it; if not, the Git that is missing the ID needs to *get* the object from the Git that has it, and now they both have the same object with the same ID.

---

<sup>3</sup>Technically, some other Git repository somewhere can use that same number for a different commit, but only if those two Git repositories never meet.  These different-commits-with-same-number are like some kind of [doppelgänger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger), and like the mythology, a commit meeting its dopppelgänger could be up for an ill fate.  But in practice this just doesn't actually happen.

---

#### What's inside a commit

That explains one way—the sure one—to *find* a commit, but not what a commit is and does for you.  We won't go deep into all the details here, but each commit has two parts:

- One part is a snapshot of all of your files, as of the way Git knew them at the time you made the commit.  These are not *changes*, but rather full snapshots.<sup>4</sup>  To keep them from making the Git database grow insanely huge, these files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  So if you make a commit with 5000 files in it, change *one* file, and make another commit, you're guaranteed that the second of these two commits doesn't have to add more than at most *one* file, because the first one has all 5000 original files in it (which might be shared with still-earlier commits too).
- The other part of a commit holds metadata: information about who made the commit, when, and why, and so on.  If you made the commit, these are your `user.name` and `user.email` and whatever you typed in as the log message.  Crucially for Git's own operation, Git adds to this metadata a set of *parent commit hash IDs*.<sup>5</sup>  This set usually has just one hash ID in it, which is what we'll illustrate here.  The (single) parent of a commit is the commit that comes *just before it*.

---

<sup>4</sup>In many ways, it would not matter if they *were* stored as changes, but the Git authors are proud of their snapshot-only ways and let it peek through here and there, so you might as well know it.  Curiously, once the files have been around for a while, the internal objects get stored as *packed* objects, where some of them are [delta-compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding), which means that they're stored as changes.  But this disappears below the object horizon: the points at which you can interact with Git to *see* the objects see them as complete files, not delta-chains.  You can't even tell if an object is still a *loose object* or a *packed object*, much less whether there's delta-compression going on.  Not all packed objects are delta-compressed; this happens only if it's *useful*.

<sup>5</sup>Technically this is an ordered list in which there should be no duplicates.  The order matters mostly in terms of the *first* entry in the list, but we won't worry about this here.

---

#### This means commits form backwards-looking chains

Suppose we have a simple linear chain of commits, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual big ugly hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  We're going to have to remember this hash ID, but in a moment we'll see how we cheat and don't *really* have to remember it, and for this posting, we'll just call it "commit `H`" anyway.

Inside commit `H`, there are two parts: a source snapshot, and some metadata.  In the metadata for `H`, Git will find the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Again, `G` stands in for some actual big ugly hash ID, but note that *we* don't have to remember it: we can just have Git fish it out of commit `H`.

We said earlier that we can *point to* a commit, and now we know how we point to it: with a hash ID.  We saved `H` somewhere and that's how we got Git to find `H`.  But `H` saves `G`'s hash ID, so `H` automatically points to `G`.  That's what we just drew above.

Commit `G`, meanwhile, has a snapshot and metadata, and therefore points to earlier commit `F`.  Commit `F` in turn points back to some still-earlier commit that we didn't bother drawing.

This goes on throughout the history—the commits in the repository *are* the history—until we get back to the very first commit someone made.  It's special in that it simply doesn't point back to an earlier commit.  That's how Git knows it can stop going backwards.

So this is what a commit is and does for us: it stores a snapshot, plus the machinery that `git log`, for instance, needs, to show us the metadata and to *compare* the snapshot to the *previous commit snapshot*, to see what *changed*.  Once `git log` has done this for commit `H`, `git log` can move back one step to commit `G` and repeat it.  This goes on until we either get tired of looking at `git log` output, or `git log` reaches that very-first-commit.

#### Branch names find last commits

To make all this work, we had to save, somewhere, the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch: commit `H`.  We could write it down, on a bit of paper or a whiteboard or something.  But why should we bother with that?  We have a *computer*.  Let's have the *computer* save it somewhere: maybe in a file, for instance, or maybe in a big database where we put in *all* our branch names, and have each one store one hash ID.

That's what Git does.  It stores branch-name-and-hash-ID pairs in files and/or some sort of database.<sup>6</sup>  In fact, Git generalizes this to storing *all* names in this database: branch names, tag names, and all the other names that Git uses.  Each one stores one hash ID.<sup>7</sup>  That's all Git needs from it, so that's all it has it do.  But that one thing gives us a lot:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Here, we now have a *name* for commit `H`.  We can use the branch name `main` to find commit `H`.  Moreover, we can add *new commits* to the chain, and when we do, Git will *automatically update the branch name*.  We'll see this in just a moment.

---

<sup>6</sup>The files, if and when they are used, *are* a database of sorts.  They're just not a very good one.  Git has, internally, the idea of a pluggable back end here, and there is ongoing work to put in a proper database.  This will solve a bunch of problems with the way Git stores these names today, although it will introduce a few new ones: databases are always hard.

<sup>7</sup>A name can store another name instead of a raw hash ID.  This is a *symbolic reference* and it only *really* works right, at the moment, for `HEAD` and some other special read-mostly cases, but it's meant as a general-purpose mechanism.

---

#### Using more than one name

Suppose we have this setup:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and we add a new branch name, such as `br1`.  The result will look like this (well, unless we tell Git more and make it look different):

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main
```

Note how *both names* select commit `H` right now.  That's about to change, as we're about to add a new commit, which we will call commit `I`.  (That's partly for convenience, and partly because we can't know the *real* hash ID until we have the commit.<sup>8</sup>)  But now we need to tell Git *which name we're using* to select commit `H`, so that it knows which name to *update*.  So we'll attach the special name `HEAD` to one branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), main
```

We get this state with `git checkout` or `git switch`, by which we tell Git: *use branch name ______* (fill in the blank) and Git figures out which commit that is and extracts it and makes it ready for us to use and so on.  If we're already using that commit, as in the case here, nothing else has to happen, so nothing else happens: we just attach `HEAD` to the new name.

Now we modify some file(s) and use `git add` and `git commit` as usual—which of course covers up a lot of detail!—but the end result is a new commit `I` whose parent is existing commit `H`.  Git writes out the new commit and then *writes the hash ID into the current branch*, which is the name to which `HEAD` is attached, giving us:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

*Now* if we switch back and forth between `main` and `br1`, Git actually has to do some real work, to swap out files that are different between commits `H` and `I`.

Note that commits up through `H` are now on *both branches*, while commit `I` is only on branch `br1`.  The commits that are "on" some branch are those that Git will find when it starts with the branch name to find the *last* commit, then works backwards.  If we tell Git to start with the name `br1`, the fact that commit `H` is the last commit of `main` is not important: we start at commit `I`, use that to go back to commit `H`, use that to go back to commit `G`, and so on.

---

<sup>8</sup>The real hash ID will depend on the exact date-and-time at which we make the commit.  Every byte of input has a huge effect on the hash ID, so if we make two otherwise identical commits with just a one-second-different timestamp, they'll get two radically different hash IDs.

---

#### Combining branches

Suppose at this point we just add one more commit like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and then go back to `main` and tell Git: *combine work on these two branches*.

Now, Git has a lot of ways to do this.  But you didn't use raw Git to do it at all.  You used GitHub (and involved multiple repositories, in the process).  When you do that, GitHub uses one of the several ways to combine work.  Which one it uses depends on which GitHub clicky buttons you use.

The most straightforward method is for Git to use what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*.  This isn't actually a merge at all.  You literally can't get GitHub to do this one though, so by definition, you must not have done that one.  (Plus, if you had, you would not be running into this problem.)

The next-most straightforward method is for Git to do a *true merge*.  True merges are sometimes *required*, but this particular case is not one that requires a true merge.  Still, GitHub will do this if you use the main big green <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button.  The result looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- main
```

(We can leave out the `HEAD` attachment here because the repository on GitHub is not one you can do work on / in, so there's no question about which branch name to use.  You literally cannot run `git checkout` or `git switch` in that repository: you have to copy the commits to some other Git repository somewhere.)

The interesting thing about this is that now, after the merge, commits `I` and `J` are on *both branches*.  (Commits `H` and `G` and earlier ones are still on both branches.)  Merge commit `M` is special in exactly one way: it has *two* parents, instead of the usual one parent, so that commit `H` can be found by working backwards one step from `M`, but commit `J` can *also* be found by working backwards one step from `M`, down the other "leg" of the merge.  Commit `M` has a snapshot, and that snapshot combines any work since `H` on `main`—though there is no such work—with all the work done since `H` on `br1`.  In this case, that means the snapshot in `M` matches the snapshot in `J`.

If you'd used this button, you would not be seeing the problem you are seeing.  So you must not have used this button.  That leaves the other two ways to merge on GitHub, which is to change the big green <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button into either <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd>.  While these two actions are not exactly the same, both of them have a common bit of key behavior: they *leave behind old commits*.

The <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button works more or less like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H------I'-J'  <-- main
```

That is, it takes the commits that are not already on the merge-target branch (in this case, commits `I` and `J` and branch-name `main`) and copies them.  This is the same kind of thing that `git rebase` does, which is why GitHub label the button the way they do.  However, having made the copies, GitHub now moves the *target branch name* forward, so that `main` names the last of the copied commits.

The <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> button works more or less like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H------IJ   <-- main
```

Here, the underlying Git repository gains *one* new commit, which I have called `IJ`; that one commit has, as its snapshot, the same snapshot you would get from a normal `git merge`, but instead of being a merge commit that indicates that commits `I` and `J` are now "on" branch `main`, there is no merge commit.  There is only a single new commit on `main`.

#### All of these are correct methods for combining work

While all three methods are *different*—the <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button making a real merge, while the other two buttons don't—they are all valid ways to combine work.  But they have different *after-effects*.  If we use the <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button, your rebase operation will work for one particular reason.  If we use the <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button, your rebase will *usually* work OK for a different reason particular.<sup>9</sup>  But if we use the <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> button, your rebase will usually *not* work.

That's fine as long as you know what you are doing, because there is a way to do your rebase that *will* work.  But you need to understand what you are doing.  Because the <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> mode of operation affects future rebases this way, it's one to consider *avoiding*—but you should still be aware of what happens with *all* the different merge methods, including doing a true fast-forward merge in your own Git repository, and then using `git push` to update the GitHub repository.

Putting all of this together, though, I would bet that you used <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> here.

---

<sup>9</sup>GitHub may deactivate the <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> option in cases where it would not work, but I have not actually tested this.  I'm not going to go into all the rebase details here anyway, as that would make this answer much longer.

---

#### How to use `git rebase --onto` to deal with these

Suppose now that you have a GitHub repository—perhaps even a fork—where you have something along the lines of what we've already drawn, but you have *two* branches besides the `main` or `master` one, like this, in your own local clone:

```
               K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Perhaps you wrote commits `I-J`, or maybe you got them from someone else—maybe even from the GitHub repository.

You now have your Git send your commits to your GitHub repository, and create name `br2`, so that on GitHub, *they* have this:

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Note how this mirrors what's in your own local repository, at this time.  They might or might not have the *name* `br1`—the name doesn't matter too much since branch names are mostly irrelevant—but they will definitely have commits `I-J` by this point: those are required to connect commit `K` back to commit `H`.

But now, at this point, whoever is in control of this GitHub repository uses the <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> button to produce, in the GitHub repository, *this:*

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main
```

They might even *delete* the *name* `br1` (if they had it), so that they have this:

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main
```

Note that all the *commits* are still there.  Git is about *commits*, not branches; the branch names merely allow us to find the commits.  So the *name* `br2` now finds `L`, which finds `K`, which finds `J`, which finds `I`, which finds `H`.  It does not matter whether or not there is a name that finds `J` directly: it suffices to find `J` by starting from `L`.

Suppose you now bring the updated commits into *your own* repository.  You run `git checkout main` (or `git switch main`) and then run `git fetch`, perhaps by running `git pull` which runs `git fetch`:

```
               K--L   <-- br2, origin/br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          IJ   <-- origin/main
```

You then move your `main` name in a fast-forward manner, perhaps by running `git pull` which (having run `git fetch`) runs `git merge`:

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

If you now run `git checkout br2`:

```
               K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main, origin/main
```

and then run `git rebase main`, your Git will enumerate the set of commits to copy: `L`, and `K`, and `J`, and `I`, but not `H` or `G` or anything earlier because those are already *on* `main`.  Next, your Git will attempt to copy commit `I`, as if by `git cherry-pick`, so that the changes from `H` to `I` can be applied to commit `IJ`.

**The attempt to copy `I` is not *guaranteed* to fail, but there is plenty of chance for it to fail because of commit `IJ`.**  If it does fail, you're presented with a bunch of conflicts.  If you didn't write commit `I` yourself, this can be puzzling!  But it's because you have told your Git to copy commit `I`, with the copy going after `IJ`.  You have asked your Git to produce:

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main, origin/main
              \
               I'  <-- HEAD [detached]
```

(the rebase operation runs with a temporary "detached HEAD", until the rebase finishes).  If the copy of `I` does work, or you manually make it work and use `git rebase --continue` to make Git proceed, Git now tries to copy commit `J` as well, so as to produce:

```
               K--L   <-- br2
              /
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H---IJ   <-- main, origin/main
              \
               I'-J'  <-- HEAD [detached]
```

This, too, is at least somewhat likely to fail.

You *can* direct rebase to *skip* these two commits, provided they did actually fail.  It was probably a bad idea to bother *trying* to copy them, though.

To avoid copying these already-present-via-squash commits, you simply tell `git rebase` *do not copy these two commits*.  In general, the right *way* to tell Git to do that is to use the `git rebase --onto` form of the command:

```
git checkout br2
git rebase --onto main br1
```

The `br1` here, which uses *your name* `br1`—which, as we can see in the drawing, identifies commit `J`—tells Git which is the *last* of the commits that it should *not copy*.  Git then won't copy that commit, and also won't copy the commit before it—commit `I`—and won't copy the commit before that, `H`, nor the commit before that, `G`, and so on.

This is the same kind of thing Git did on its own when you tried:

```
git rebase main
```

except that when you did this without the separate `--onto` part, the set of commits that Git decided *not* to copy had as the *last* such commit, the commit that the name `main` identified, i.e., commit `IJ`.  Now, commit `IJ` was *never going to be in the list of commits to copy* because it's not *on* `br1`, but that's OK: `IJ` points backwards to `H`, so Git won't try to copy commit `H` either.  The important thing with the `--onto` was to make sure that Git didn't try to copy commits `I` and `J` *too*.

So, in the end, we just want to tell Git *copy commits ending at the current commit (`L`), but excluding commits going backwards from the name or hash ID I gave (`br1` = commit `J`), with the target being to go after `main`*.  To make the target and the exclude part be two different things, we need the `--onto` form of `git rebase`.<sup>10</sup>

Of course, all of this is predicated on the idea that someone used <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> on GitHub.  You didn't say that someone did that, but it definitely sounds like it.

---

<sup>10</sup>Technically, you could use `git rebase -i` and simply delete the correct set of `pick` commands, too.  But the `--onto` method is better because it is so much easier to get right.  Note that you can combine `--onto` and `-i`, too, in situations where that makes sense.

Comment: But if you look at my comments, I specifically suspected a squash merge and the OP explicitly denied it.

Comment: @matt: he hadn't answered at the time I posted, though. :-)

Comment: True enough, I'm just saying that if we take the OP's "just a merge into master" the whole argument falls to the ground... It seems to me that we can't answer at all without further information :(

Comment: @matt: My guess is still that he used the clicky button on the web site, and it was already set to "squash and merge".

Comment: Yeah, that invitation to squash merge sitting right there on GitHub (or whatever), as if it were some sort of good thing to do, is definitely a trap. That's why I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076935/341994 to show how to enact the issue.

Comment: Yea sorry im not entirely sure which method of merge is used. We just do `arc land` and that takes care of it, not sure what's under the hood specifically.