# After merge of release branch to master, release still shows as being so many commits ahead of master

Tags: git

In Azure Git, we branch from `master` to `release`, then from `release` to any number of `feature` branches, say 4. We PR `feature` branches into `release` deleting the `feature` branches as part of the completion. Before merging `release` into `master`, `release` shows as being 0 behind | 4 ahead. Upon executing merge from `release` into `master` and completing the PR, I would expect `release` to show as being 1 behind | 0 ahead of `master`. In reality, it shows as 1 behind | 4 ahead. All past `release` branches show being that many more merges behind (which I understand) and as many commits ahead as many features were completed in the given release -- which I don't.

Is this a normal behavior? What would we need to change about the way we merge to have the merged `releases` show as being 0 commits ahead of `master`?

Comment: Before we go any further: when you complete a PR, are you using a _true_ merge or a fake merge such as "squash" or "rebase"? Same for merging from release into master: is this a _true_ merge?

Comment: @matt We squash merge from features to release. If we also squash merge from release to master, would that explain the behavior? When creating a PR, I go with the defaults. I will have to pay attention next time to see if squash merge is selected. If they called it a fake merge, maybe fewer people would opt for it.

Comment: Yeah, on GitHub once you pick "squash" you get "squash" by default thereafter. Maybe Azure behaves similarly. I regard this entire feature as the work of the devil. A "squash" merge is _not a merge_. It should _never_ be used with long-lived branches.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the answers to my questions are:

1. Yes, if "squash changes" is checked when completing the PR.
2. Uncheck "squash changes".

Thanks to @matt and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops

Comment: Here is a [rule of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65097943/184546) that I think should work in your situation.